# How Es6 rest and spread is working

Tags: javascript, lambda, ecmascript-6

I now have the following code

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var raw =[
  {
    key :"name",value:"henry"
  },
  {
    key :"age",value:"old"
  },
  {
    key :"food",value:"matooke"
  },
  {
    key :"kids",value:"Acacia"
  },
  {
    key :"garbageA",value:"kasailoA"
  },
  {
    key :"garbageB",value:"kasasiroB"
  },

]
const endShape = _(raw)
.filter(({key}) =>!/garbage/.test(key))
.map(({key,value})=>({[key]:value}))
.reduce((acc,curr)=>({...curr, ...acc}));

console.log(endShape);
```

The code works well and I was following a tutorial.
I understand up to the .map() method.
Though I have failed to get a clear explanation of what

```
.reduce((acc,curr)=>({...curr, ...acc}));
```

is doing.  How does is come up with this correct result ?

```
{ kids: 'Acacia', food: 'matooke', age: 'old', name: 'henry' }
```

Comment: What you have is a syntax error in ES6. If it "works" for you, you seem to be using [an experimental transpiler](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/)

Comment: Which syntax error ? please explain clearly

Comment: `{...curr, ...acc}` is not valid ES6.

Comment: Let me research about that

Comment: Destructuring object will probably be an ES7 feature.

Comment: @Erazihel Nope. It's not in any current standard, not in ES6 and neither in ES7 or ES8.

Comment: @Bergi it's in stage 3 though https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread

Comment: What are you guys talking about ? What is stage 3 ? is it a standard?

Comment: New features added to JavaScript are discussed and tested through different stages: see http://2ality.com/2015/11/tc39-process.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the `map` function outputs this:

```
[
  {
    name: 'henry'
  },
  {
    age: 'old'
  },
  {
    food: 'matooke'
  },
  {
    kids: 'Acacia'
  }
]
```

The `reduce` will then work like an `Object.assign`. It will iterate through the array above and add each key/value pairs to the accumulating object, which is an empty object at the start. That's why you get:

```
{ kids: 'Acacia', food: 'matooke', age: 'old', name: 'henry' }
```

The accumulation object is `undefined` at start but it doesn't matter thanks to the destructuring:

```js
const foo = undefined;
const bar = { a: 'b' };

console.log({...foo, ...bar })
```

Comment: Well i know that in theory @Erazihel.But  where is the a accumulation object

Comment: Isnt it supporsed to be passed as the second argument to the reduce function ?

Comment: @HenryBbosa I've updated my answer to show you why the first accumulation can be `undefined`.

Comment: Oh so itas innitially undefined.. Thank you so much :)